# How to remove two pixels from the edge of masked raster

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, satellite

I have a raster file, which has empty/masked areas on the edges and then all data inside is not masked. Basically, a sub-swath of satellite data interpolated to rectangle. All is fine, except that sometimes the edges are having artificial lines (possibly some interpolation problem), and thus I'd like to remove two pixels on each of the edges on the actual data.

[image]

In the image, the black area is masked data. The problematic edge is the one on the actual data and masked data border. So, I would like to remove two pixels from the actual data on this data/black area border. It would not be a problem to write a simple python or C program to just travel the whole raster pixel by pixel, but I'm afraid it would take a long time to make it efficient, and I have a lot of files to process.

To illustrate the problem, a zoomed in view to border area and take a look at the upper edge (the intensities are not final, just to illustrate the effect).

[image]

Is there any optimized standard tool available for such task?

Comment: Not clear which edge you are referring to. Please edit your question to include a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @StuSmith, hope it is clear now.

Comment: You could try erosion, as referred to in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/185941/128665).

Comment: Thanks @Matt, at least I know the correct term to look for, now.

Comment: So, basically applying the erosion algorithm to the mask of the data should do the trick. There seem to be a plenty of tools that can do it.